# Saving raw PCM bits into compressed audio AAC/AMR file

Tags: android, encoding, audiorecord

I am writing an application for recording user audio using `AudioRecord`. I am saving the raw PCM bits into a `short[]` array (since my encoding is 16 bit PCM). After the recording is complete, I want to compress this audio data and save it to a file. I was wondering if there is some high level API in Android SDK that could help me with this.

Currently, I am trying to use `MediaCodec` and save it AAC format. Firstly, I am creating a `ByteBuffer` with my raw data using the following code

```
// allocating the array with length 2 * length of the byte array because we are creating a
    // ByteBuffer.
    final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(mDataArray.length * 2);

    // putting value in the ByteBuffer ..
    for(short elem : mDataArray) {
        byteBuffer.putShort(elem);
    }
```

Since, I want to support API level 16, I guess I have to use the deprecated set of functions (mentioned as **Synchronous Processing using Buffer Arrays (deprecated)** in this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)). Is this correct way forward?

The other problem that I see going forward is how to save the encoded buffers into a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) API, which is pretty straightforward, and has been supported to varying degrees since API 1.

Otherwise, the difference between the deprecated Buffer Arrays and the standard synchronous method is in fact very small.  I was in the same position as you, wanting to support API 16, but I couldn't use MediaRecorder.

I created routines to fill and drain the buffers:

```
private void fillCodecInputBuffer(ByteBuffer inputBuffer, int bufferId) {
    ... code to fill input buffer ...
}

private void drainCodecOutputBuffer(ByteBuffer outputBuffer, int bufferId) {
    ... code to drain output buffer ...
}
```

... then I called these from a separate routine for pre- and post-lollipop platforms.  This way the newer platforms can encode more efficiently (they can't if using the deprecated methods).

Pre-lollipop:

```
ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();;
ByteBuffer[] encoderInputBuffers = encoder.getInputBuffers();

private void processEncoderKitKat() {
    /* uses old pre-LOLLIPOP (v5) method */
    final int ENCODER_TIMEOUT_US = 0; /* we poll only - was 10000 */
    int inputBufferId = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(ENCODER_TIMEOUT_US);
    if (inputBufferId >= 0) {
        fillCodecInputBuffer(encoderInputBuffers[inputBufferId], inputBufferId);
    }
    int outputBufferId = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(encoderBuffer, ENCODER_TIMEOUT_US);
    if (outputBufferId >= 0) {
        drainCodecOutputBuffer(encoderOutputBuffers[outputBufferId], outputBufferId);
    } else if (outputBufferId == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
        encoderOutputBuffers = encoder.getOutputBuffers();
    }
    if ((encoderBuffer.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0)
            isFullyEncoded = true;
}
```

... note this old method may need to notify you that the output buffers have changed, and you'll need to reset your array to suit.

Post-lollipop:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void processEncoderLollipop() {
    /* uses post LOLLIPOP (v5) method */
    final int ENCODER_TIMEOUT_US = 0;  /* we poll only */
    int inputBufferId = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(ENCODER_TIMEOUT_US);
    if (inputBufferId >= 0) {
        fillCodecInputBuffer(encoder.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId), inputBufferId);
    }
    int outputBufferId = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(encoderBuffer, ENCODER_TIMEOUT_US);
    if (outputBufferId >= 0) {
        drainCodecOutputBuffer(encoder.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId), outputBufferId);
    }
    if ((encoderBuffer.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0)
        isFullyEncoded = true;
}
```

I'm pretty sure you could structure the (recommended) asynchronous way to call the fill/drain routines as well, but I haven't tried it yet.